# An Arraylist of Arrays or os there a better way?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

So thanks to the wonderful people here i've managed to get something semi workable, still have a couple bugs but maybe you guys can help me figure it out. So far none of the solution provided were a exact match (which is why i havent up voted them) but they did help me look at things in a new way and get things moving forward. So here is the current problem.

First the code then the explination

```
                RaceButtons[RaceCounter] =  new JToggleButton();
                RaceButtons[RaceCounter].setIcon(RCiconSM);
                RaceButtons[RaceCounter].setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
                RaceButtons[RaceCounter].setContentAreaFilled(false);
                RaceButtons[RaceCounter].setActionCommand(temp_race.getRaceNameString(RaceCounter));
                RaceButtons[RaceCounter].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                                Race race = new Race(1, 1, GenderList[PHYSICAL_SEX]);
                                race.setRaceID(race.getRaceIDFromString(ae.getActionCommand()));
                                //System.out.println(race.getraceID());
                                        if (RaceButtons[race.getraceID()].isSelected()){
                                            RaceButtons[race.getraceID()].setBorderPainted(true);
                                            RaceButtons[race.getraceID()].setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.blue,2));
                                            MyRaceArray.add(new Race(race.getraceID(), 1, GenderList[PHYSICAL_SEX]));
                                        }else{
                                            RaceButtons[race.getraceID()].setBorderPainted(false);
                                        };
```

So first i create an array of Toggle buttons and when you click it it draw the border and then getting it's info i can add it to the array for races but this lives me with another problem i cant quite figure the logic off. Namly if there are already selected button it adds another instances to the button, it shouldn't do that it should ignore iexaisting entries but that means i have to check the arry for a matching object of type Race withthe same info right? What's the best way to do that?
And when you deselect it how do i remove that same object.

Comment: Make a class that holds all those fields. Pseudo code *. Your program is racist :)

Comment: Agreed. That's what abstraction is about :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how your code should look like with a Race class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Race {

    private int raceID;

    private double purity;

    private int strMod;

    private int dexMod;

    private int conMod;

    private int wisMod;

    public int getRaceID() {
        return raceID;
    }

    public void setRaceID(int raceID) {
        this.raceID = raceID;
    }

    public double getPurity() {
        return purity;
    }

    public void setPurity(double d) {
        this.purity = d;
    }

    public int getStrMod() {
        return strMod;
    }

    public void setStrMod(int strMod) {
        this.strMod = strMod;
    }

    public int getDexMod() {
        return dexMod;
    }

    public void setDexMod(int dexMod) {
        this.dexMod = dexMod;
    }

    public int getConMod() {
        return conMod;
    }

    public void setConMod(int conMod) {
        this.conMod = conMod;
    }

    public int getWisMod() {
        return wisMod;
    }

    public void setWisMod(int wisMod) {
        this.wisMod = wisMod;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Race [raceID=" + raceID + ", purity=" + purity + ", strMod="
                + strMod + ", dexMod=" + dexMod + ", conMod=" + conMod
                + ", wisMod=" + wisMod + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //create a list of race objects
        List<Race> raceCollection = new ArrayList<Race>();

        //create a race object
        Race race = new Race();
        race.setRaceID(1);
        race.setPurity(0.75);
        race.setStrMod(5);
        race.setDexMod(7);
        race.setConMod(-2);
        race.setWisMod(3);

        //add race object to collection
        raceCollection.add(race);

        //You can create and add multiple objects of race to the collection


        //Iterate your list and print the objects
        for(Race raceObj:raceCollection) {
            System.out.println(raceObj);
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Why use get functions and set methods rather than properties?  Properties would allow you to use the initialization shorthands like: `Race race=new Race{RaceId=1,Purity=.75,StrMod=5,DexMod=7,ConMod=-2,WisMod=3};`

Comment: or `var raceCollection=new { new Race(...), new Race(...) };`

Comment: its the nature of the anonomous classes, the races don't exsist to reference once we move to the Action Performed, so i have to beuild a new generic Race Object, then get the Actioncommand of the active button to figure out what the hell was clicked on and makes the nee temp race object match, THEN Add that to my Collection, but after i do that i cant figure out how i remove it. There has to be a better logic structure but i cant seee it

Comment: You can add constructors to initialize the objects. The following statement seems to be javascript and not java "var raceCollection=new { new Race(...), new Race(...) }; ".

Comment: i have constructors both default and paramaterized in my Race Class but the problem as i see it is thee Race object doesn't exist after i make my buttons save as a Action Command. And i just dont see a reasonable way to make it persistant so i can fetch it's info to build the Collection short of making seperate buttons for each...and there's 40+ races so that's impractical.

Comment: I am not sure if i understand u completely. I think you are trying to save an object of Race once the button is pressed and want to save it in a collection. If that is the case, you need to create a list outside your actionPerformed at a global level perhaps, then everytime button is pressed, create an object of race and add it to the global list. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yup thats what i do "MyRaceArray" is a arraylist of type Race, but once i Add to it i'm not sure how to remove from it or check to make sure that extries already exist of the exact same Race. I imagine i'll need some kind of Comparison Clause but do i need to write a compareTo into my race class or is there a simpler way? And how do i remove, do i need to build a remove menthod, it's removing from an Array list so i can put a remove in Race that wouldnt do aynthing but how do i Format a remove for Arraylist to find a object match?

Comment: @NekoLLX If there is a possibility to move to a different collecion then consider using HashSet, which does not allow duplicates. You will have to implement equals and hash method in your race class. Whenever you will add something to the HashSet, it will call equals to make sure whether the object already exist, if not then it will put but if it already exists it will discard it. But if you have to use arraylist, then u will have to write your own logic to check whether object already exist. Everytime you insert, you will have to iterate the list to do the existence check and act accodingly.

Comment: which is untimatly what i did, now everything is working nicely. I dunno if anyone is interested but if they are let me know a'll i'll post up the source

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to make it *work* using an ArrayList of arrays, but that possibly isn't the best way in the long run. It can be very fiddly and error-prone to deal with - what happens when you insert a new race or attribute, but forget to to change the index somewhere?

Arrays and ArrayLists are usually best reserved for situations where you actually have a sequence / list (often with a meaningful sequence order).

In your case I'd be more inclined to adopt a [prototype model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming). Typically in Java you would represent each race with a `HashMap` (or a data structure containing a HashMap), there the map represents the relationship between the "Attribute ID" and the "Default Value".

Creating a new elf is then just a case of initialising the elf's attributes using the default values from his race (or a average of different races, if you want...)

Some people may suggest making an OOP class with lots of named fields. This can also work, but IMHO a prototype model is better - it gives you much more flexibility in the long run. You often want to process large groups of attributes in the some way, and doing this is pretty messy if you have to refer to each of the attribute fields individually.

Comment: yeah, nothing i do seems to get me a good result, i even tried to jusr Juned's example to build something and while i'm not getting compile errors i cant see a reasonable way to remove the races. The big problem as i see it (which i will update my source to hellp illustrate) is I generate the buttons that show the race options programically, so there are a lot of annonomous and local classes

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Race
{
    private final int raceID;
    private final double purity;
    private final int strMod;
    private final int dexMod;
    private final int conMod;
    private final int wisMod;

    public Race (int raceID, double purity, int strMod, int dexMod, int conMod, int wisMod)
    {
        this.raceID = raceID;
        this.purity = purity;
        this.strMod = strMod;
        this.dexMod = dexMod;
        this.conMod = conMod;
        this.wisMod = wisMod;
    }

    public int getRaceID ()
    {
        return raceID;
    }

    public double getPurity ()
    {
        return purity;
    }

    public int getStrMod ()
    {
        return strMod;
    }

    public int getDexMod ()
    {
        return dexMod;
    }

    public int getConMod ()
    {
        return conMod;
    }

    public int getWisMod ()
    {
        return wisMod;
    }

    @Override public String toString ()
    {
        return "RaceID:" + raceID
            + " purity:" + purity
            + " strMod:" + strMod
            + " dexMod:" + dexMod
            + " conMod:" + conMod
            + " wisMod:" + wisMod;
    }

    @override public int hashCode ()
    {
        return raceID;
    }

    @override public boolean equals (Race r)
    {
        return (r != null && this.raceID == r.getRaceID());
    }

    @override public Object clone ()
    {
        return new Race(this.raceID,this.purity,this.strMod,this.dexMod,this.conMod,this.wisMod);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        // simple test
        ArrayList<Race> races = new ArrayList<Race>();

        Race a = new Race(0,0.5,1,2,3,4);

        Race b = new Race(1,0.75,2,3,4,5);

        Race c = new Race(2,0.25,-1,-2,-3,-4);

        races.add(a);
        races.add(b);
        races.add(c);

        for(Race race : races)
        {
            // System.out.println(race.toString());
            System.out.println(race);
        }
    }
}
```

Then we have the visual model, which can be handled like this:

```
class RacePanel implements ActionListener
{
    private Map<Integer,JToggleButton> r;
    private Map<Integer,Race> f;

    public RacePanel()
    {
        r = new TreeMap<Integer,JToggleButton>();
        f = new TreeMap<Integer,Race>();
    }

    public JToggleButton add (Race a)
    {
        JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton();

        button.setIcon(RCiconSM);
        button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.setActionCommand(a.getRaceID());
        button.addActionListener(this);

        r.put(a.getRaceID, button);
        f.put(a.getRaceID, a);
    }

    public void remove (int raceID)
    {
        r.remove(a.getRaceID);
        f.remove(a.getRaceID);
    }

    // When a button is clicked
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // related race
        Race a = f.get(e.getActionCommand());

        // clicked button
        JToggleButton b = r.get(e.getActionCommand());

        // ..
    }

    public ArrayList<JToggleButton> getButtonList ()
    {
        return new ArrayList<Value>(r.values());
    }

    public ArrayList<Race> getRaceList ()
    {
        return new ArrayList<Value>(f.values());
    }

    public Race getRace (int raceID)
    {
        return f.get(raceID);
    }

    public JToggleButton getButton (int raceID)
    {
        return r.get(raceID);
    }

    // ..
}
```

Comment: Generating a race isn't the problem, or even pinting the contents of the collection in loop, the problem comes from the fact that to build the buttons that make the races i use a loop so refering back to them to add or remove from the collection get's hairy when the function itself that hold the add/remove is inside a annonomous inner class, insdie the action perform, of a looped and rebuilt single button instance.
If you have idea on how to add and remove elements to the collection which are created inside a annonomous local button I'd love to hear it

Comment: looks promising, havent worke to much with map but the rest is familiar, and i'll have to make some tweaks to make it intergrate with my existing layout, but it looks promising. I'll get back to all you with how things turn out

Comment: you code didn't really gell with my code but it did give me ideas, so thanks for that. I've updated the OP with the modified code to try and get over the last herdles

Comment: I provided a technical solution for your issue of the relation between a button & an object when clicked .. fitting that into your context is your concern